Would Duaa be accepted even with limited ability
السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته
I am a student preparing for an upcoming medical exam. I have been making duaa since Ramadan that I get a certain score in my medical exam that I knew it is extremely hard for me to get despite my efforts. I have recently changed my duaa to get a perfect score in the exam. This score I knew is IMPOSSIBLE for me to get regardless of my work. So, is it permissible to ask Allah of such duaa or not? I also alhamdulillah, all thanks to Allah I pray at masjid and I do my best in my worship and in my studying but the stimulation exams show results very far from the perfect score I am dreaming of

Asalam Alikum
Allahumabarak!
Brother, no matter how impossible it seems, you gotta admit you came a long way Allahumabarak just to even get to the level of taking the exam therfore proving it's not impossible.
Do your best but make alot of duas and do not lose hope and trust Allah as no way your exam can ever be greater than  his will
Things to say in dua
1.Praise Allah
2.Repent for sins
3.What you want
4.Prophet muhammad/his family/companions
